# Awaiting Socket Operations

Tags: c#, async-await

Given the following code, modified from Stephen Toub's article.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/12/15/10248293.aspx

```
    public async Task Start(CancellationToken token)
    {
        while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await this.acceptCount.WaitAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                break;

            var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
            args.UserToken = new SocketFrame
                                 {
                                     CancellationToken = token,
                                     Buffer = null,
                                     Message = null,
                                 };

            // How do I manage this additional task?
            args.Completed += (s, e) => this.AcceptInbound((Socket)s, e).Wait(token);
            if (!this.socket.AcceptAsync(args))
                await this.AcceptInbound(this.socket, args);
        }
    }

    private async Task AcceptInbound(Socket sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {

        var frame = (SocketFrame)e.UserToken;
        this.acceptCount.Release();
        Socket connectedClient = e.AcceptSocket;

        var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        args.SetBuffer(new byte[0x1000], 0, 0x1000);
        var awaitable = new SocketAwaitable(args);

        while (!frame.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await connectedClient.ReceiveAsync(awaitable);
            var bytesRead = args.BytesTransferred;
            if (bytesRead <= 0) 
                break;

            if (this.AppendByteArrayToFrame(frame, args.Buffer, bytesRead))
                this.reader.MessageReceived(frame.Message);
        }
    }
```

How do I avoid the `Wait` on the `args.Completed` event?
I want exceptions raised in AcceptInbound to bubble up, so I really don't want to wait there.

What I am trying to achieve is to bind the AcceptInbound task to the current task, so that when I wait on the current task, the exceptions raised are caught.

Comment: What's wrong with just `args.Completed += async (s, e) => await AcceptInbound((Socket)s, e);`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks i2arnon, that helps a bit, what I am trying to achieve is that I Wait on the Task returned by Start. I want the exeptions raised in AcceptInbound to be raised on the same thread as the Task returned (and waited for) on Start. I think I need to use the SynchronisationContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register an `async` event handler (which is the only place `async void` is appropriate). That allows you to `await` instead of blocking with `Wait`:

```
args.Completed += async (s, e) => await AcceptInbound((Socket)s, e);
```

If instead you want `Start` to handle completion and exceptions from all these tasks then I would store them all until `Start` completes and then use `Task.WhenAll` to make sure all operations completed and rethrow any exception they may produced:

```
public async Task Start(CancellationToken token)
{
    var tasks = new ConcurrentBag<Task>();
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // ...
        args.Completed += (s, e) => tasks.Add(AcceptInbound((Socket)s, e));
        // ...
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to ensure that exceptions raised on the async event handler are caught in the Task returned by Start when it's waited on?

Comment: it turns out I was also not using the SocketAwaitable correctly. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Hi @i3arnon. Subscribing asynchronously to that event doesn't await for it being raised. That is what @Jim wants to happen. If you look carefully at his question will notice that the second method, `AcceptInbound` reads from a socket which appears as a result of an Accept TCP/IP operation of a server socket (basically it is a client counterpart socket). By calling `AcceptAsync` you just trigger the accept operation. Subscribing in either async or non async modes is not a solution as long as you don't somehow "Await for the execution of the OnCompleted event handler".

Comment: @i3arnon So to answer your question, that is why `TaskCompletionSource<T>` is relevant to this question.

Comment: @EduardDumitru I disagree with your understanding of the OP's question.

Comment: @i3arnon Could you point out what is different in your own understanding from mine so that the purpose of this website is respected and consequent users arriving at this particular question can make sense of what is going on?

Comment: @EduardDumitru "Subscribing asynchronously to that event doesn't await for it being raised. That is what Jim wants to happen." nothing in the question or comments point to that being the case.

Comment: I'll make an analogy: A user wants to a) connect to a database asynchronously b) read data from that database asynchronously. Now, the user doesn't explicitly state the fact that b) cannot happen before or during a). It is obvious that b) can only take place after a) has completed. Your answer is something like, should you have two tasks representing both a) and b), here's how you can await for the completion of both. That doesn't ensure order, which is highly needed in the case of the analogy. In the current case, Jim accepts a new connection from a client and then reads data from that client

Comment: So I disagree with your understanding of the question and I'll explain why. To answer the question one must be skilled in async programming which in your case is true but also to understand the object of discussion and, in this particular case, be skilled in using the classes from the `System.Net` namespace, have experience with plain ol' socket connections and know what is possible and when. If I asked about connecting async to a database and running an async query gainst it wouldn't it've been obvious that I need them to happen in the proper order without explicitly stating it?

Comment: @EduardDumitru Yes. If someone asks a question on SO you should answer **that** question. You can also add more information beyond  that, but you need to address the actual question, not your perceived one. Second of all, this answer ensures order. b always happens after a. You probably mean they should happen sequentially in a loop and again, this is for the OP to decide.

Answer (score 0):

[TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) to the rescue!

Take a look at this:

```
private TaskCompletionSource<Something> _tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<Something>();

public void FinishAwait(Something result) {
    _tcs.SetResult(result);
}
public void FailAwait(Exception exception) {
    _tcs.SetException(exception);
}

public async Task<Something> M() {
    var result = await _tcs.Task;
    return result;
}
```

This a very customised way of controlling when and how a particular `Task` completes.

You could use that to `await` a custom built task which is manually triggered by the completion of the `AcceptAsync` operation's event handler.

In your case, the generic argument `T` can be `object` because we only needed it to be `void` and `object` is the most benign of all types.

You could then await that intermediate task inside the `Start` method, just before awaiting the `AcceptInbound` method's `Task`.

Your problem was not that Exceptions are not passed from
callee to caller via await call but rather that you were
calling `AcceptIncomming` too soon.

Simply receiving `true` in the call to `AcceptAsync` doesn't mean that the "Accept occurred" but rather that is successfully started.

Take a look at that part of the code:

```
public async Task Start(CancellationToken token)
{
    while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await this.acceptCount.WaitAsync(token).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
            break;

        var args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        args.UserToken = new SocketFrame
                             {
                                 CancellationToken = token,
                                 Buffer = null,
                                 Message = null,
                             };

        TaskCompletionSource<object> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

        // How do I manage this additional task?
        args.Completed += (s, e) => {
            switch (e.SocketError) {
                case SocketError.Success:
                    tcs.SetResult(null);
                    break;
                default:
                    tcs.SetException(new SocketException());
                    break;
            }
        };

        if (!this.socket.AcceptAsync(args)) {
            // receiving a true value here 
            // only means that AcceptAsync
            // started successfully
            // we still need to 
            // "await for the Completed event handler"

            await tcs.Task; // this will automatically throw
                            // if tcs.SetException(...) was used
            // also, it will return null if all is well
            // but most importantly, it will allow us to 
            // know when to call the next method

            await this.AcceptInbound(this.socket, args);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is that relevant to the question?